# Building Qt 4 with intel compiler = unresolved bug

Tags: c++, qt4, qmake

I was trying to build Qt 4.7.2 with intel parallel studio compiler and I noticed unlike the vcc it fails with an error message:

Catastrophic error: cannot open precompiled header file "qmake_pch.pchi"

Googling the message returned one single link: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-15390

It says the issue is currently unresolved but mentions a workaround:

> To workaround it then the CFLAGS in the Makefile need to be set to create it's own pch file like:
>
> ```
> CFLAGS = -Yc -FIqmake_pch.h -Fpqmake_pch.pch $(CFLAGS_BARE) $(CFLAGS)
> ```

However, adding those lines to the win32-icc qmake configuration didn't do anything for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Precompiled headers are a build optimization. If they cause issues, just build Qt without them. It's a one-time build anyway, if you're not working on Qt itself.

Comment: Nokia offers builds only with MigW and msvc, which do not integrate within visual studio using intel compiler, they also offer source libraries I cannot build with the intel compiler in order to be able to use Qt at all. How do I build without the precompiled header? And won't that cause problems later on?

Comment: You build without precompiled headers by removing the relevant flags. This will not cause problems if you remove all of them., except of course for a slow build.

Answer (score 0):

Calling configure runs qmake and qmake produces a Makefile under "qmake" folder of the source tree just before catastrophic error. You need to edit that file instead of editing the qmake configuration file. Search for the

```
CFLAGS = -Yuqmake_pch.h -FIqmake_pch.h -Fpqmake_pch.pch $(CFLAGS_BARE) $(CFLAGS)
```

line in the "qmake/Makefile" and change it to

```
CFLAGS = -Yc -FIqmake_pch.h -Fpqmake_pch.pch $(CFLAGS_BARE) $(CFLAGS)
```

Now make the edited Makefile read-only using explorer! Then call the

```
configure -platform win32-icc
```

again! The configure script will try to overwrite Makefile but will not succeed. Now the Makefile is how we want and the configuration process will complete.